# Setting image from path to custom button in Android

Tags: java, android

Im trying to create a custom button in Android.
The button can take parameters though XML which looks a bit like this when used from a layout:

```
customimagebutton:src="@drawable/my_button_image"
```

I then implemented a class that is working together with my button (which is defined in xml). In that class I can read the passed parameters, but here is where my problem is.

When I get the above resource passed, it is passed as a path.

```
"//res/drawable-xhdpi/my_button_image.png"
```

I now want to use this path, and set the image to a ImageView. The problem is I cannot seem to get a valid handle to the resource. I have tried

```
 getResources().getIdentifier( <full path or just the name, with and without .png>, "drawable, null);
```

but that always returns 0. And I have tried to create a Uri with

```
"android.resource://<the path>"
```

but the ImageView dont want to show it anyway. Anyone got a tip or knows if I´m using the API the wrong way?

Answer (score 2):

You can use below line to get a bitmap from resource;

```
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.my_button_image);
```

You can use below line to set image directly and leave rest to system

```
setImageResource( R.drawable.my_button_image);
```

**Edited** :

**getResources() :** The Android resource system keeps track of all non-code assets associated with an application. You can use Resources class to access your application's resources. You can generally acquire the Resources instance associated with your application with getResources().

**R.drawable.my_button_image :** The Android SDK tools compile your application's resources into the application binary at build time. To use a resource, you must install it correctly in the source tree (inside your project's res/ directory) and build your application. As part of the build process, the SDK tools generate symbols for each resource, which you can use in your application code to access the resources , `if you are using Eclipse then , your project is builded automatically`

Comment: A big problem is that I don´t have the resourceId (the int value from the R file) to my image, I only get the path as text passed. Im trying to get that int value with getResources().getIdentifier but that only returns 0 (i.e. not a valid resource).

Comment: Do you have an R file generated under generated sources package? If so do you have a constant my_button_image in it?

Comment: You are setting the customimagebutton:src="@drawable/my_button_image" property. The only problem you will have is that if you change your file name (let's say from my_button_image.jpg to something else), you will have to update the above code accordingly.

Comment: I do have an R-file, I know how to use resources from it. But, in this case I only have the path (i.e. "//res/drawable-xhdpi/my_button_image.png").

Comment: Oh ok. I encountered a similar situation as well. My not so brilliant solution was to map every resource to its String name. You may have a global static map that is initiated at the creation of application that maps every String name of the resource to its actual integer id. When it is needed you can get the integer id with the String "my_button_image".

Answer (score 0):

I got up with a solution, I think the main error was that I didn't get the right package to getIdentifier.

Here is some source (may have minor errors since I had to remove some parts).

My custom button (java):

```
public class CustomImageButton extends RelativeLayout
{
...

    public CustomImageButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);

        LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inf.inflate( <my_xml_file> , this, true);

        TypedArray arr = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomImageButton);
        CharSequence imageSrc = arr.getString(R.styleable.CustomImageButton_src);
        if (imageSrc != null)
        {
            String fileName = new File("" + imageSrc).getName();
            fileName = fileName.substring(0, fileName.indexOf("."));

            int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(fileName, "drawable", <my_top_level_package_very_important_to_get_right>);
            ImageButton button = ((ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonImage));

            button.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(resId));
        }
    }

...
}
```

and then in attrs.xml, "src" is used above.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <declare-styleable name="CustomImageButton">
        <attr name="src" format="string" />
    </declare-styleable>
...
</resources>
```

Then it can be used from an layout xml, note the "xmlns:customimagebutton":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:customimagebutton="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
....>

    <my.package.custom.MyCustomButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        customimagebutton:src="@drawable/my_image" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi i have followed this procedure to solve this , i just downloaded this image in AsyncTask .

```
actualUrl = new URL("http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRhyKydwWIfkRw6O1VJB7JCzy3aevgyDnn4rN6wmWRflAxSGCwrvA") ;
HttpURLConnection cn = (HttpURLConnection)actualUrl.openConnection();
cn.connect();
stream = cn.getInputStream() ;
```

After it i save this file using this code :

```
   FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(object.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+"/imagename.png");
   Log.i(object.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath(), "complete-path");
  (BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream) ).compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
```

Now to display this image in the image view i have used this code Section

```
Bitmap bit = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(object.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+"/imagename.png");
if ( bit == null )
    Log.i("bit is null","Completed");
img.setImageBitmap(bit);
```